# Alternatives to PHP header function

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mime-types

I'm working on a website that has a number of style sheets all of which need to be handled as PHP scripts server-side. My ***.htaccess*** file looks something like this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

This causes a small problem as the mime type of the http-response's `Content-Type` field is then set to `text/html` instead of `text/css`.

Obviously I can fix this by adding `header('Content-Type: text/css')` to all of my files but is there a better way?

Can I do this from within the .htaccess file? None of the directives offered by *[mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html)* or *[mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html)* seem to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try:

```
php_value default_mimetype "text/css"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just add a **.php** extension to all of your CSS files; this will cause the server to pass all of the "normal" CSS as just that, whereas all of your dynamic, PHP-generated CSS should be parsed. After that, it's just a matter of slightly modifying the way in which you link your stylesheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css.php" />
```

Though that's always done the trick for me, there's a slight chance you may need to explicitly declare the MIME type of your CSS files using PHP's **header()** function, like so:

```
header('Content-type: text/css');
```