# I want to change Content-Type of the default in php

Tags: php, css, apache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternatives to PHP header function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482392/alternatives-to-php-header-function)

I mention it in httpd.conf as follows to let you interpret css as php

```
<FilesMatch "\.css$">
   ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch
```

Content-Type is output as text/html and is troubled.
Therefore I added the next cord to the top of the css file.

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/css"); ?>
```

It's not cool...
Do you know how to output text/css ?

Comment: This is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482392/ , which seems to have the solution.